# Can I use "model.fit()" in "for" loop to change train data in each iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a large dataset and it doesn't fit in memory. So while training, SSD is being used and epochs take too much time.

I save my dataset 9 part of `.npz` file. I choose first part (part 0) as validation part and I didn't use in training.

I use code below, and `acc` & `val_acc` **result were fine. But I feel I do big mistake somewhere.** I didn't see any example like this

```
for part in range(1,9):
 X_Train, Y_Train = loadPart(part)
 history = model.fit(X_Train, Y_Train, batch_size=128, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

and also I load part 0 as Test data

`val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(X_Test, Y_Test)`

I tried to check `val_acc` after train each part of dataset and I observed `val_acc` was increasing.

**Could you please let me know if this usage is legal or illegal and why?**

EDIT:

I tried fit_generator but it still use disk during training and ETA was about 2,500 hours. (in model.fit with whole dataset it was about 30 mins per epoch) I use code below:

```py
model.fit_generator(generate_batches()), steps_per_epoch=196000,epochs=10)
```

```py
def generate_batches(): 
   for part in range(1,9): 
      x, y = loadPart(part) yield(x,y)

def loadPart(part): 
   data = np.load('C:/FOLDER_PATH/'+str(part)+'.npz') 
   return [data['x'], data['y']
```

and X data shape is (196000,1536,1)

EDIT 2:
I found an answer in [github](
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4446). It says it is ok with call `model.fit()` multiple times in for but still I don't sure what happens in behind.What is the different between call `model.fit()` multiple times and call once with whole dataset.

Answer (score 2):

If your model does not fit in RAM the keras documentation suggests the following (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-keras-with-datasets-that-dont-fit-in-memory):

> You can do batch training using model.train_on_batch(x, y) and model.test_on_batch(x, y). See the models documentation.
>
> Alternatively, you can write a generator that yields batches of training data and use the method model.fit_generator(data_generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs).

This means you could try to further split your training data into batches of 128 on your SSD and then do something like:

```
import glob
import numpy as np

def generate_batches(data_folder):
    while True:
        batches_paths = glob.glob("%s/*.npz" % data_folder)
        for batch_path in batches_paths:
            with np.load(batch_path) as batch:
                x, y = preprocess_batch(batch)
                yield (x, y)


model.fit_generator(generate_batches("/your-data-folder"), steps_per_epoch=10000, epochs=10)
```

The preprocess_batch function would be responsible for extracting your x and y from each .npz file and the steps_per_epoch argument in the fit_generator function should be the rounded up value of your number of data samples divided by your batch size.

More info:

- https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edit my question with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dask also, this chunks the data into smaller sections by default if you have a set that doesnt fit into RAM

Answer (score 0):

If you are training as described in your question and it is trained in one session, then there is no difference. But if you are training in multiple sessions and continuing from previous training then you should save your model either after every epoch(i.e, are training through 9 sets in 1 epoch) or in your case you can save after every set of the dataset(i.e, after every 1 of 9 dataset) and in every session load the weights using `model.load_weights("path to model")` before you continue your training.

You can save model after every epoch using `model.save("path to directory")`.